# How to perform append with if condition for multiple array

Tags: python, for-loop

I am writing the following code in Python, I want to accomplish the following using a for condition

```
                if (datetime_obj.hour==7):
                    hour7.append(a)
                if (datetime_obj.hour==8):
                    hour8.append(a)
                if (datetime_obj.hour==9):
                    hour9.append(a)
                if (datetime_obj.hour==10):
                    hour10.append(a)
                if (datetime_obj.hour==11):
                    hour11.append(a)
                if (datetime_obj.hour==12):
                    hour12.append(a)
                if (datetime_obj.hour==13):
                    hour13.append(a)
                if (datetime_obj.hour==14):
                    hour14.append(a)
                if (datetime_obj.hour==15):
                    hour15.append(a)
```

hour are empty arrays.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish, or what your current issue is?  Why is the code you have not acceptable?  That will help answerers point you in the right direction for fixing or improving your code

Comment: Hi Tom, I am hoping for a simpler approach as this way is too lengthy and I have more if conditions to add.

Answer (score 1):

Make `hour` a list of lists, e.g., `hour = [[] for _ in range(24)]`, such that `hour[7]` would give you whatever you have for `hour7`, etc. Then you can simply do

```
hour[datetime_obj.hour].append(a)
```

No ifs or loops.

If the values that `datetime_obj.hour` takes aren't consecutive values from 0 to some number, then use a dictionary of lists instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your code will be greatly simplified by abandoning the specific references to each empty list (e.g. `hour1`, `hour2`).  Rather, you should create some structure which holds the lists, and allows you to access them in a sensible way.  The existing answer uses a nested list, which is a good option. Another way would be with a `dict`:

```
hours = {i:[] for i in range(24)}
hours[datetime_obj.hour].append(a)
```

`hours` is initialized as a dictionary where each key is an integer (representing an hour of the day) and each value is a separate empty list.  You can select those empty lists by directly using `datetime_obj.hour`, and then append your `a`.

You can check out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables) for a relevant discussion; for both convenience and functionality, avoiding these repetitive sequential named variables is recommended!